# Adding an Objective-C framework to a Swift XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, github, frameworks, xcode7

I know this is a very simple - maybe obvious - question, but I've been struggling with it for a while. I'm working on a SpriteKit project in XCode (using Swift) and I'm trying to add this [SKEasing Framework](https://github.com/buddingmonkey/SpriteKit-Easing) from GitHub.

I've already downloaded and extracted the zip file, and I did everything that 孙博弘 [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37829156/4805995) including the bridging header (which I made the  with the help of [this](https://medium.com/swift-programming/merge-objective-c-static-library-into-swift-using-mosquitto-87ce0b6ec513#.rotet05gh) site);

[image]

However, the framework doesn't seem to be working. I can't use any of the actions provided by this library. Is there something I'm missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your project Swift or Objective-C?

Answer (score 3):

You don't add the project to your project. 
First open the SKEasing project in xcode by itself. Set the build target to generic iOS device. (With the pop up in the top left corner of the xocde project window.) Then use the Build command (under Product) and when that's done run Archive. There should be a library built now under the products folder (left side of project window). Control click on the library name and select Show in Finder. This will lead you to the library. Copy this file to your project and you should be good to go.

Comment: I did this, but I still can't use this actions. I tried coding "import libSpriteKit-Easing" at the top of my .swift file but it doesn't work.

Comment: Now I have an error every time I run which says: "linker command failed..." "library not found for lSpriteKit-Easing"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you were in swift. You need to add a bridging header to access the objective-c lib from swift. Here's an example of how to do it;  https://medium.com/swift-programming/merge-objective-c-static-library-into-swift-using-mosquitto-87ce0b6ec513#.h8q4gha1b

Comment: But I can't add the .h files to a bridging header because the library isn't a folder, it's an .a file.

Comment: i'll try to build the example over the week-end.

Comment: Hi, could you show me how to do it in a completely new answer and we delete this one?

Comment: John, could you answer please, I'm giving bounty.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `.a`, you should use it as follow img.

[image]

Comment: i take a screenshot in swift